# Google sheets / Javascript: How do I 'get cell' value which is dynamic?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, google-sheets, cell

I have a spreadsheet I use as a 'dashboard' connected to a Google Form which is hanging on a Google site, taking live (quality department) data from providers about bad orders. When ever one of these claims is filled in in the form it creates a new row appending itself to the bottom of the spreadsheet- My 'column A' is a code for that new claim.

I would like to create a new folder (this part I have managed) using the code from column A as the name of the folder. To do this I would need a dynamic code which got the value from the new row in column A. I don't know how to do this- any help? My current code is:

```
function getNewCell() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var range = sheet.getRange("A:A");

var x = 0
//insert while loop here?

var cell = range.getCell(x, 1);
Logger.log(cell.getValue());
}
```

I've absolutely no idea how to do get the dynamic value. Either a while loop until it finds an empty space and then go up one cell? Or a loop which runs from the bottom up until it reaches a cell with a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the last row of a Google spreadsheet sheet, use [Sheet::getLastRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow).

From the above link

> #### getLastRow()
>
> Returns the position of the last row that has content.
>
> ```
> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
>  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
>
>  // This logs the value in the very last cell of this sheet
>  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
>  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
>  var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn);
>  Logger.log(lastCell.getValue());
> ```

Comment: Thanks Ruben I've managed to get the right cell. Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Rubén. I gave it the right answer, and also the upvote however until I have enough points on the site apparently you won't see the score change. It's possible at the time you sent this I hadn't done any of that though! I can't remember now. Thanks again.